# Why does this C++ program initialize variables to 0?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int val1 = 0;
int val2 = 0;
int val3 = 0;
```

I don't understand why I have to put these `= 0`, is there any meaning behind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialisation of values to 0 or anything else is optional. If you don't though, the variable could contain anything...

Answer (score 4):

This actually depends on *where* you declare the variables.

If you declare them as local variables (e.g. inside a function) then the compiler and runtime system will not initialize them, their values will be *indeterminate*. Using such variables except to initialize them will lead to *undefined behavior*.

If you declare them as global variables, then the compiler and runtime system will make sure that they are zero-initialized.

If you declare the variables as member variables inside a class or structure, then their initialization depends on if you have a constructor or not. If you *don't* have a constructor, or or a defaulted constructor, then the compiler will automatically generate a constructor which will default-construct the (non-static) members, which for `int` variables is the same as zero-initialization. If you *have* a constructor, the (non-static) member variables will be uninitialized just like local variables.

Comment: Static variables would also be zero initialised by default. Personally I would never make the assumption that this zero initialisation is done for you though, if may be part of the C standard but it costs nothing to make it explicit an clear.

Answer (score 1):

when declaring a new variable, it is stored on your current stack. it MIGHT have garbage in it from previous uses, so the only way to make sure you're new variable initial value is indeed 0 is setting it to zero when declaring